# On the dimension of subspaces of the vector space given by the product of polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I was asked this question orally so feel free to also correct how the question is written.

Given the vector space of polynomials in the variable $x$ with degree $\le 4$ and the vector space of polynomials in the variable $y$ with degree $\le 4$.

Taking the product of the elements of the two vector spaces gives an other vector space of what dimension? What is the dimension of the subspace of all polynomials that are divisible by $y$? and by $x^2+1$?

My answers:

1)The dimension of the vector space would be $5^2$ because $(x^4, x^4y , x^4y^2, x^4y^3, x^4y^4, x^3, \dots, y^3, y^4 ) $ is a basis.

2) the form of a polynomial divisible by $y$ is $ay^4+ by^3 + cy^2 +d y  $ so the dimension would be $4$.

3)After performing long division the form of a polynomial divisible by $x^2 + 1$ is $x^4a + bx^3 +cx^2 + bx -a +c$ a basis for the space of these polynomials is $(x^4-1, x^3 + x, x^2 +1)$ so the dimension is $3$.

Am I correct in my answers? Is this a valid question or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Your reasoning for number one is sound.

Comment: For part two are you sure they don't want the subspace of the space from part one?

Comment: @GregoryGrant yes I think they want that.

Answer (score 1):

> 2

The subspace is generated by polynomials of form $x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}$ where $0\le \alpha\le4$ and as the elements are divisible by $y$, $1\le \beta\le4$. So the required dimension is $5\times4=20$.

> 3

If the polynomial is $(x^2+1)p(x,y)$, $p(x,y)$ can't have any power of $x$ greater than $4-2=2$. So in this case $0\le\alpha\le2$ and $0\le\beta\le4$. So the required dimension is $3\times5=15$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I still don't really understand the answer to question $3$, why can't $\alpha$ be equal to $2$ for instance?

Comment: @Monolite Take a look at [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division), the degree of remainder is always less than quotient.

Comment: But we aren't looking at the remainder we are looking if the polynomial is divisible by $x^2 + 1$, i.e., the remainder is zero.

Comment: @Monolite You're correct. I misread the question. I edited my answer.